# How to use CppFlow library with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a system for traffic sign recognition. In order to be fast I decided to code image preprocessing and inference in C++ and training in Python. For training of CNN I use TensorFlow with Keras. I came to the part when I need to classify detected sign and for that I need to load my pretrained model. I would like to do it with CppFlow library, but I don't know how to use it with Visual Studio 2019. Can someone help me do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Part that confused me the most was that CppFlow is just a wrapper with headers, so you need CppFlow and TensorFlow C API. Also here is the link that helped me a lot with including dependencies in Visual Studio 2019: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160